# NEST mapping group

Tags: nest

I'm beginning with NEST and I want to group my properties.

```
namespace Prototype.Logs
{
    [ElasticType(Name = "msglogs")]
    internal class Msg : BaseLog
    {
        [ElasticProperty(Name = "exception")]
        public string BaseException { get; set; }
        public string InnerException { get; set; }
```

I want to map groups like for instance

```
  "exception" : {
    "baseexception" : "blablabla() : blabla",
    "innerexception" : "blablabla() : blabla",
  },
```

Instead I get a flat document :

```
"baseexception" : "blablabla() : blabla",
"innerexception" : "blablabla() : blabla",
```

I tried to search on the NEST doc but I did not find anything.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your exception object should be broken out into it's own class and mapped as an inner or nested object of Msg.

Something like this:

```
class MyExceptionClass
{
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "baseexception")]
    public string BaseException { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "innerexception")]
    public string InnerException { get; set; }
}
```

...and then in your Msg class:

```
[ElasticType(Name = "msglogs")]
internal class Msg : BaseLog
{
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "exception")]
    public MyExceptionClass Exception { get; set; }
}
```